# System.Web.Optimization is not accessible within Razor views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Basically I'm trying to use bundles in my layout and I'm getting following error: `the name styles does not exist in the current context`. I know it's caused by lack of System.Web.Optimization and there are some standard ways to fix it. I've tried:

- Re-installing System.Web.Optimization package in NuGet
- Adding `<add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />  in one and even second Web.config`
- Adding `<add assembly="System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />`to  in outer Web.config.
- Deleting csproj.user file.

I've restarted VS after those changes but none of them fixed my issue. Moreover when I type `@using System.Web.Optimization` in a view it throws error `The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`. Last but not least - I reference `System.Web.Optimization` in Application_Start method of Global.asax.cs where I register bundles.

Comment: add namespace in ~/Views/Web.config file and then try unload and then reload your project

Comment: I've just done. Has not helped.

Comment: where did you place your namespace ?

Comment: In <system.web.webPages.razor><pages><namespaces> - in a view's web.config. In <pages><namespaces> in main web.config.

Comment: did you set pageBaseType=System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage in pages node ?

Comment: Yes. I did it like you've said.

Comment: you did all the previous steps as you mentioned in the question?

Comment: Yes, exactly. None of it has helped. I think the problem may be in creating web project from Empty template...

Comment: You say you re-installed System.Web.Optimization in NuGet but isn't it the Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization package?

Comment: @Landeeyo Maybe. try to create an internet application instead of empty project when you creating MVC application, so it will do all these things automatically .

Comment: @FrebinFrancis I've just did it. Problem disappeared. I'll try to compare configuration to see what's missing. Or there's something more than web.configs and NuGet packages or it was subtle mistake or a bug... Thank you for support, anyway.

Comment: I had the same problem. I think `System.Web.Optimization` is old and Microsoft issues its substitution that is [Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/1.1.3). Try to install this from NuGet Packages manager and you should be OK.